# Tikz: arrow heads on all edges on a \draw path

Tags: tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \node (1) {1};
  \node (2) [right of=1] {2};
  \node (3) [right of=2] {3};
  \draw [->] (1) -- (2) -- (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image: result]

How does one make it so that both lines have an arrowhead (without having two `\draw`s)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `\draw` line into this:

```
    \draw [->] (1) edge (2) (2) edge (3);
```

You can also use the tikz library `arrows.meta` like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, every edge/.style = {draw, -to}]
        \node (1) {1};
        \node (2) [right of=1] {2};
        \node (3) [right of=2] {3};
        \path (1) edge (2)
              (2) edge (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit of a shame it has to be so verbose.

Comment: @EddBarrett  `\def\edto(#1){\edge (#1)(#1) }` and then `\draw[->] (1) \edto(2) \edto(3);` should work ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in this simple case to use a commutative diagram with `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrows={line width=.5}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd} 
1 \arrow[r] & 2 \arrow[r] & 3
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]